# I don't know where the internal error is occurring.It says that the API key is not valid and that I need to pass a valid API key

Tags: flutter, android-studio

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:time_trackerpractice/app/sign_in/sign_in_button.dart';
import 'package:time_trackerpractice/app/sign_in/social_sign_in_button.dart';
import 'package:time_trackerpractice/common_widgets/custom_raised_button.dart';
import 'package:time_trackerpractice/services/auth.dart';

class SignInPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignInPage({Key key,@required this.auth, @required this.onSignIn}) : super(key: key);
  final AuthBase auth;
  final void Function(User) onSignIn;


Future<void> _signInAnonymously() async{
  try {
    final user = await auth.signInAnonymously();
   onSignIn(user);
  }catch(e){
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Time Tracker'),
          elevation: 20.0,
        ),
        body: _buildContent(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContent() {
    return Padding(
        padding:EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center ,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Sign in',
              textAlign:TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 32.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),

              SizedBox(height: 48.0),
              SocialSignInButton(
                assetName: 'images/google-logo.png',
                text: 'Sign in with Google',
                textColor: Colors.black87,
                color:Colors.white,
                onPressed: (){},
              ),
            SizedBox(height:8.0),
            SocialSignInButton(
              assetName: 'images/facebook-logo.png',
              text:'Sign in with Facebook',
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Color(0xFF334D92),
              onPressed:() {},
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          SignInButton(
            text: 'Sign in with email',
            textColor: Colors.white,
            color: Colors.teal[700],
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
            SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            Text(
              'or',
              style: TextStyle( fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.black87),
              textAlign:TextAlign.center,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            SignInButton(
              text: 'Go anonymous',
              textColor: Colors.black,
              color: Colors.lime[300],
              onPressed: _signInAnonymously,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

I am working on a flutter course on udemy.I am trying to sign in to the go anonymous button,but I keep getting this error that the API key isn't valid but I triple check everything and I still don't know were I went wrong.I was wondering where the internal errors occurring.And how can I make the API key valid.After I made the API valid how can I pass the API key so I can log in to the go anonymous button.

Comment: could you show `AuthBase.signInAnonymously()`? or whatever implementation of that you are using?

Comment: Did you download google-services.json from Firebase and add it to you app? That is where the api key is located.

Comment: @h8moss here is the implementation and  also added google-services.json from Firebase  and added it to the app.


class Auth implements AuthBase{

  final _firebaseAuth =FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Stream<User> authStateChanges() => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();

override
  User get currentUser => _firebaseAuth.currentUser;

override
  Future<User> signInAnonymously() async{
    final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
    return userCredential.user;
  }